# 15.04 "Software Updater" claims there are updates, then realizes there are none

Tags: upgrade, update-manager, 15.04

I've recently updated my 14.10 installation to 15.04 (it went even smoother than I expected). After installation, running the Software Updater showed this:

[image: upgrade_window]

Pressing "Partial Upgrade" asks for my password, shows the standard upgrade window, but then closes and this shows up:

[image: upgrade_error]

If I click on "Continue", it simply tells me that "all software is up to date".

[image: upgrade_up_to_date]

Can I do anything about this? Maybe it didn't fully install even though it claims it did? (I am also noticing screen tearing, which should've been fixed in the update, so that could be an indicator for that.)

Comment: Press `Partial Upgrade`.

Comment: The first "Continue" was meant to say "Partial Upgrade" (my bad, I've edited the question).  If I press `Partial Upgrade`, it shows what you see in the first screenshot.

Comment: In response to your comment in the answer, the command is `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is in the first screenshot you sent: "A previous upgrade which didn't complete". Could you open a terminal and issue:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If it shows error (you may) run

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

or

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

depending on the type of problem that apt found (it will suggest you what to pick). Sometimes the Software Updater is not enough to fully upgrade packages.

In any doubts just post it here.

Comment: I've already tried running `update` and `upgrade` (with no success). 
| 
`sudo apt-get upgrade` simply returns [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10874063/). 
| 
`sudo apt-get -f install` provides a similar output, only without listing the names of the 8 packages. 
| 
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a` doesn't execute at all. (`-a` is not a valid option.) Running `dpkg-reconfigure` on the above packages didn't make a difference either.

Comment: Turns out I had to run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: My mistake, I entered "sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a" and what I really wanted to say is "sudo dpkg --configure -a". D'oh! Glad you find a solution. :-)